# How can I use a library such as requests-html to substitute image sources of local files on the web server in html source code to the url + local file

Tags: python, html, image, web

Remember when we were younger and we copied the source code of a website and did not understand why it broke so much?

Well as I know now it is because if you do not have webserverfile.png downloaded, it can not render.
How can I use python to replace

```
<img src='webserverfile.png'> to <img src='webserverurl/webserverfile.png'>
```

Note: I do not need help getting the source of the site, I know how to do that with requests.

Also Note: If you can just use native python syntax like replace or startswith than you do not need to use for example bs4 or requests-html to do it.

Also if the site already uses webserverurl/webserverfile I do not want to replace it to webserverurl/webserverurl/webserverfile.png

Comment: It's easiest to do this at the time of download. You can try using https://www.httrack.com or run a command like `wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --no-parent http://example.org`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637191/complete-the-relative-paths-to-absolute-using-python